# What would religious debates look like in a religion designed by a time-traveler to help mankind?

Tags: time-travel, religion, science-in-society

A time traveler, Roy, is marooned in the ancient era.  Time and place are negotiable: ancient Greece, Roman Judea, ancient China, etc.  There's no hope of getting back, but he's an intelligent fellow with a good background in basic science.  Roy has made a good living for himself by setting up a distillery, but he decides to make a bigger impact.  He starts a new religion, Royism, but with the intent that the rituals and tenents are of practical benefit to believers.

For example, the holy text contains the following: "Before readying water for drinking, your ROY commands that you bring it to a boil and recite the litany of belief."  And the litany of belief just happens to take around three minutes to recite.

His goal was to encode as much modern, practical knowledge into his religion as possible so that humans could benefit from the knowledge even if they didn't necessarily understand it.  Roy is familiar with the way religions can mutate over time, he knows a Royble (that's a Royist Bible) can't just have diagrams of spinning wheels or seed drills in it.  He formulates it to be pretty concise and resistant to being corrupted in translation.

Now fast forward a thousand years.  Royism has spread widely, in large part, thanks to the observable benefits, but human foibles are ever-present.  Over the years misinterpretation, heresies, and schisms have multiplied.  For example, ultimately there are religious wars fought over whether the ROY intends for the water to come to a rolling boil or a simmer.  But just one example doesn't make for an interesting world, and besides elementary hygiene, I'm drawing a blank on what Roy might have included and therefore what was misinterpreted and misconstrued over time.

In short, besides hygiene practices, what basic ideas from the present that can be summed up in a paragraph of plain language would have been of concrete benefit in the past?

Comment: I'd say "love thy neighbor" and "bless your enemies," and "treat others as you want to be treated," but things didn't end too well for the last guy that suggested that...

Comment: This is either Story Based, what do you want them to learn, or Primarily Opinion Based, what one person and another think is "better" are rarely identical.

Comment: Whilst I like the idea behind the question, it doesn't seem like a good fit for this site's Q&A format.

Comment: Roy is seeing people around him dying from malnutrition in years of failed crops, cholera, measles, smallpox, chickenpox and whooping cough so I think these should be his objectives.

Comment: you can look at food laws in Judiasm (Kashrut) or Islam (Halal). A lot of them sound like very sensible food safety. And they have survived just fine over the centuries. I also remember some early chapters of Bible and/or these religions have rules on washing hands, handling death (body disposable, quarantine the family, etc.)

Comment: @CarlosMartin measles, chickenpox and whooping cough are probably outside of his ability to do anything about. "Crop failure" is underspecified, but he'd be limited in his ability to handle that, too. He only has his brains with him, and people aren't generally omnicompetent.

Comment: The biggest challenge is the very idea of sacred scripture in 5th century BCE Greece... They simply did not have sacred scriptures, they never even thought of having sacred scriptures, and the idea of a religiously normative written text would have been completely alien to them. Ah, and in that place, at that time, religion was an intensely local affair. The rituals of Athens were not practiced in Corinth (40 miles distance); trying to establish uniform and *alien* rituals in 5th century BCE Greece would be a quick way to duplicate the final experience of Socrates.

Comment: Roy's precise location in time and space is negotiable.  For worldbuilding purposes, he could just as easily pop up in Bethlehem in 4 BC.

Comment: @BaldBear a lot of the Old Testament restrictions on "ritual impurity" actually make more sense when viewed in the light of "sanitation best practices," such as not touching a corpse (spread of disease), avoiding pork (trichinosis and tapeworms), avoiding shellfish (red tide poisoning), washing hands before eating (self evident), draining blood from meat before consuming (food safety and spoilage). IIRC there's also a recipe for a kind of "soap" that when analyzed turned out to be one of the best antiseptics of the time. I wish I could remember the passage...

Comment: @stix It's in Leviticus 19: lists of things that make you unclean, like touching corpses, dead animals, etc, and gives instructions to take a heffer and burn it completely on cedar wood (which would release oils from both the fats and cedar) then to collect the ashes and soak them in clean water (releasing lye) and mix in hyssop (which has antibacterial properties). here are [some more examples](https://biblicalfoundations.weebly.com/bibles-medicine.html).Another interesting point in Lev 19 is that anyone that refuses to go through the cleansing ritual has to be cut off from everyone...

Comment: @AndyD273 Ahh yeah that's it. I wonder if anyone's thought to make Leviticus soap. Fat + lye + fragrance = handsoap after all...

Comment: Ryan North wrote a book for this exact situation:

"How to Invent Everything: A Survival Guide for the Stranded Time Traveler"

Comment: @kleer001 It's also a common trope in the Japanese Isekai genre, especially "Ideal Sponger Life," "How a Realist Rebuilt the Kingdom," and "Ascendance of a Bookworm" just to name a few... Main character dies and reincarnates/gets summoned to another world, usually one that's farther behind us in technology, MC uses knowledge of our world, profits immensely.

Comment: @BaldBear Most of the laws in Leviticus deal with some layer of health and hygiene, including avoiding incest, which was common in the nations around them, (as well as in later europe). Most of the rest deal with what we'd call common law, and wouldn't be out of place in a lot of our modern courtrooms, and interpersonal relationships, like take a day off from work and spend time with your family. It's all really far ahead of it's time...

Comment: Dangit, Numbers 19, not Leviticus... my bad.

Comment: @AlexWood You know your edit has just completely invalidated Alexander's answer, that's considered bad manners and is frowned on here.

Comment: @Confoundedbybeigefish. Apologies.  I was trying to get the question to better meet the site's standards.

Answer (score 0):

**This is impossible to tell, because it all depends on the exact language of Roy's testament**

All religious debates arise from the lack of specifics in religious texts. The underlying reasons for schisms and splinters can be very mundane, but formally they boil down to one or few statements in a holy text that can be interpreted differently. For example, if a text says that water needs to be boiled, the questions would be about how exactly it needs to be boiled and what should be noted as a boiling starting moment.

Thus, discussing topics of possible debates is like discussing possible loopholes in a legal contract without seeing the contract itself. We may theorize that some people would not like to boil water every time and would be looking for ways to circumvent this requirement, but we can't tell what specific points would be debated.

Comment: good points. An example: the scripture says: "put water on fire, once bubbles appear, recite the prayer, and only then water is safe to drink".  But people  will make bubbles by stirring the water. So Roy would have to explain that its the heat that drives sickness out of water, and bubbles are merely proof of heat.

Comment: Respectfully, I disagree.  There are a lot of doctrinal differences in Christianity that do not at all depend on exact language but rather different interpretations of core elements that underlie any specific text.  E.g. Mormons don't ascribe to the concept of original sin.  Anabaptists rejected infant baptism.  I'm sure those believers marshall specific verses to defend their position, but I'm more interested in what the different positions are in broad terms.

Comment: @Alex Wood so this is not about the ambiguous language but rather the lack of the language covering details. Like, "thou shalt boil water" - but what to do with other liquids?

Comment: @Alexander Exactly.  No matter what concept Roy put in the Royble, some group somewhere is going to screw it up.  I can probably think of the screw-ups myself, but need a little help with the concepts to use.  I did think of crop rotation for example.  Obviously, there are two denominations now waring over whether to rotate the crops counterclockwise or clockwise.